# How to hide cell if "active" column is "no" in Swift 3/Xcode 8

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I'm just in the process of putting a prototype app together in Swift 3.0.

At the minute, all API information is Parsed in to table cells. What I was hoping to do was introduce the facility where if I set an "Active" column in my database to "no" then how could I prevent that cell from showing in the table view?

Currently the code is this:

```
func configure(offence: Offence) {
   if let name = offence.name, let act = offence.act {
       self.textLabel?.text = name
       self.detailTextLabel?.text = act
   }
```

I've tried playing around with if/else statements but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: can you show some more code? you have an array of `Offence` objects that you use as the tableview's datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `Offence`s have an `active` property you can use it to filter your server response and only show those with the `active` property set to `true`. something like this:

```
struct Offence {
    var name: String
    var active: Bool
}

class YourViewController: UITableViewController {
    // all the offences you get from the server
    let offences: [Offence] = []

    // only the active offences - use those as your datasource!
    var visibleOffences: [Offence] {
        return offences.filter { $0.active }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return visibleOffences.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = visibleOffences[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: you should better use a `didSet` observer on `offences`  to set the `visibleOffences` only once to avoid to filter it on every call to `visibleOffences`

Comment: or to leave the login in YourViewController untouched use the filter when you set the offences: `myViewController.offences = myOriginalOffencesFromDatabase.filter{$0.active}`

Comment: @muescha: Other ways to go, yeah!